# package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist

Tags: maven, hadoop

I'm a new learner of Hadoop and I was packaging the codes from Tom White's Hadoop Guide Book (4th Edition) with maven and I encountered issue for chapter 22's codes. It notice me that "package org.apache.hadoop.record" is not exist.

I googled this package and found that it has already been deprecated by Avro. Avro and other dependent packages are installed by maven. You can see from the result below that other compile task are successful.

```
[INFO] 53 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Project .............. SUCCESS [ 0.406 s]
[INFO] Common Code ........................................ SUCCESS [ 2.231 s]
[INFO] Chapter 2: MapReduce ............................... SUCCESS [ 0.194 s]
[INFO] Chapter 3: The Hadoop Distributed Filesystem ....... SUCCESS [ 0.398 s]
[INFO] Chapter 5: Hadoop I/O .............................. SUCCESS [ 0.376 s]
[INFO] Chapter 6: Developing a MapReduce Application ...... SUCCESS [ 0.336 s]
[INFO] Chapter 8: MapReduce Types and Formats ............. SUCCESS [ 0.651 s]
[INFO] Chapter 9: MapReduce Features ...................... SUCCESS [ 0.344 s]
[INFO] Chapter 12: Avro ................................... SUCCESS [ 5.353 s]
[INFO] Chapter 13: Parquet ................................ SUCCESS [ 1.922 s]
[INFO] Chapter 15: Sqoop .................................. SUCCESS [ 0.148 s]
[INFO] Chapter 16: Pig .................................... SUCCESS [ 0.173 s]
[INFO] Chapter 17: Hive ................................... SUCCESS [ 0.426 s]
[INFO] Chapter 18: Crunch ................................. SUCCESS [ 1.371 s]
[INFO] Chapter 19: Spark .................................. SUCCESS [ 13.280 s]
[INFO] Chapter 20: HBase .................................. SUCCESS [ 0.390 s]
[INFO] Chapter 21: ZooKeeper .............................. SUCCESS [ 0.090 s]
[INFO] Chapter 22: Case Studies ........................... FAILURE [ 0.196 s]
[INFO] Hadoop Examples JAR ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Snippet testing .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Example Code ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.732 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-12T10:56:53+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 90M/360M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ch22-case-studies: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[4,57] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[5,53] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[6,47] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[35,46] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[38,65] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[100,55] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[110,71] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[120,57] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[218,66] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[9,57] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[10,73] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[11,69] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[12,73] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[13,74] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[14,69] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[53,53] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[56,36] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[57,55] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[60,38] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[146,58] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[146,136] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[147,38] package org.apache.hadoop.record.meta does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[226,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[227,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[231,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[232,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[236,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[237,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[241,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[242,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[246,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[247,43] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[260,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[261,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[265,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[266,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[270,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[271,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[275,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[276,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[280,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[281,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[285,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[286,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[290,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[291,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[295,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[296,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[300,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[301,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[305,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[306,44] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/myclass/hadoop-book/ch22-case-studies/src/main/java/fm/last/hadoop/io/records/TrackStats.java:[321,29] package org.apache.hadoop.record does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR] mvn -rf :ch22-case-studies
```

Also attach my environment variables here.

```
#JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
#HADOOP
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.0.0-alpha3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/myclass
#HIVE
export HIVE_INSTALL=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_INSTALL/bin
```

Could anyone help me with this issue? Thanks

Comment: If the package is deprecated it is most likely that the current version you are trying to install is no longer present, therefore you error. Either update your error module to current version or downgrade the versions of the dependencies of this module.

Comment: It's on Github, yes. File a Github issue.

Comment: You can update Avro here. https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/4e/book/pom.xml#L16

Comment: Also note that Hadoop 3.0 did not exist when that book was created, so best to stick with at least 2.6.x

Comment: Will it works fine if I package codes with Hadoop 2.6 or 2.7 and run those jar in 3.0?

Comment: Issue fixed. I downgraded the hadoop for packaging to hadoop 2.7.3 and issue no longer existed.I'll try to run those jars. Thanks all!